# array length is zero in reactjs with yup validation

Tags: arrays, reactjs, yup

i don't know why array length is always show 0
this is my code which my array consist 5 element

also i use objects { [error.path]: error.message } to save errors still cannot display length

```
const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required(),
  lastName: yup.string().required(),
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
  password: yup.string().min(8).required()
})
export const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  })
  let name =[]

  formSchema.validate(values, { abortEarly: false }).catch((err) =>
    err.inner.forEach((error) => {
      name.push({ [error.path]: error.message })
    })
  )
  console.log(name)
  console.log(name.length)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>{name.length}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah the length check happens before the array push. Move it into the catch after the pushes or make this array part of state and that way it will rerender when things change

Comment: `validate` seems `async`. Try `.then()` or `await` whole validation process for pushing results before rendered.

Comment: tried both ways but nothing was change still same thing if you can that was my whole code make it work and pasted :)